# Unrecognized selector when deleting a NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'd like to delete a core data object by fetched the object first, so

in FetchObject.m

```
- (void) actionDelete {
    AModel *aModel = [[aModel alloc] init];
    AObj *aObj = [aModel readDataWithAttributeName:@"keyword" attributeValue:@"value"];

    [aModel deleteObject:aObj];
}
```

aObj did fetch and obtain. 
in AModel.m

```
- (void)deleteObject:(AObj *)aObj
{
    [appDelegate.managedObjectContext delete:aObj];
    NSError *error;
    if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}
```

But, when I test it, here came out an error

```
-[NSManagedObjectContext delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa43ece0
```

After searching the solution a bit, seems like the target has been release before deleteObject.
Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: paste the whole error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code is causing the issue:

```
[appDelegate.managedObjectContext delete:aObj];
```

Replace it with:

```
[appDelegate.managedObjectContext deleteObject:aObj];
```

[**NSManagedObjectContext**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext_Class.pdf) doesn't have a `delete` method, it only has a `deleteObject` method.

> `- (void)deleteObject:(NSManagedObject *)object`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ***object***
>
> ```
> A managed object.
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> When changes are committed, object will be removed from the uniquing
>   tables. If object has not yet been saved to a persistent store, it is
>   simply removed from the receiver.

Comment: thanks a lot. may i ask what's the difference between delete and deleteObject?

Comment: @pqteru: There is no function called delete in NSManagedObjectContext. But in C++ there is a function called delete for releasing allocated memory. (I think you know that, we can use all the functions available in C & C++ in Xcode).